# Finding number of images formed by shuffling pixel location and average of Euclidean distance

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing

There is a 2000 x 2000 image I, where all pixels in the left half are white and those in the right half are black. A new image (Inew) of the same size is formed from I by shuffling the pixel locations. Then, What is the total number of possible Inew images and What is the average of Euclidean distance across all these possible Inew images?

Comment: Probably best not to cross-post at this point, but if you don't get a response try here: https://math.stackexchange.com/